# Prettier whitespace error

Tags: html5, typescript, vue.js, pug, eslint

En los ficheros Vue del proyecto, en los cuales estoy usando pug, si despues de una etiqueta html pongo un espacio, me detecta un error, como en la siguiente imagen. El objetivo es que no salte dicho error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dependencias globales relevantes del proyecto:**

- Versión de prettier:   2.7.1
- Versión de eslint:     8.23.0
- Versión de typescript: 4.8.2

**Configuración de prettier:**

```
"prettier": {
        "semi": true,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "trailingComma": "none",
        "bracketSpacing": true,
        "printWidth": 120,
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "useTabs": false,
        "quoteProps": "as-needed",
        "arrowParens": "always",
        "endOfLine": "lf",
        "pugPrintWidth": 140,
        "pugBracketSameLine": true,
        "pugClosingBracketPosition": "last-line"
    }
```

EslintConfig:

```
"eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "plugins": [
            "security"
        ],
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "@vue/typescript/recommended",
            "plugin:prettier/recommended",
            "plugin:security/recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 2020
        },
        "rules": {
            "no-undef": "off",
            "security/detect-object-injection": "off",
            "security/detect-non-literal-regexp": "off",
            "security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
            "no-console": "warn",
            "no-throw-literal": "warn"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Probaste modificando [`htmlWhitespaceSensitivity`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity) en la configuración? Es decir, agregar `"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"`